# How to use Asyncio to access multiple APIs simultaneously in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, web3py

I'm using asyncio to listen to eth websocket so that I can get all NFT transactions in real time, and the code is here which runs well:

```
alchemy_http_url = 'https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/gPXApmtTzATb-g4sFtpEXuL5-8i9uaqF'
alchemy_ws_url = 'wss://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/gPXApmtTzATb-g4sFtpEXuL5-8i9uaqF'

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(alchemy_http_url))

options721 = {'topics': [web3.sha3(text='Transfer(address,address,uint256)').hex()]}
request_721 = {"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["logs", options721]}
request_string_721 = json.dumps(request_721)

async def get_event_721():
    async with connect(alchemy_ws_url) as ws:
        await ws.send(request_string_721)
        while True:
            try:
                message = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=60)
                event = json.loads(message)
                if len(event['params']['result']['topics']) == 4:
                    result = event['params']['result']
                    tx_hash = result['transactionHash']
                    print(tx_hash)
                pass
            except:
                pass

asyncio.run(get_event_721())
```

by running the code above, the terminal will print dozens of tx hash every 10 seconds.

but only tx hash is not enough for my app, i will use these tx hash to acess another API to get the details of these tx hash by calling web3.eth.get_transaction(tx_hash), so I add a function to do that:

```
async def get_event_721():
    async with connect(alchemy_ws_url) as ws:
        await ws.send(request_string_721)
        while True:
            try:
                message = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=60)
                event = json.loads(message)
                if len(event['params']['result']['topics']) == 4:
                    result = event['params']['result']
                    tx_hash = result['transactionHash']
                    print(tx_hash)
                    **print( await asyncio.wait_for(get_transaction(tx_hash),timeout=60))**
                pass
            except:
                pass

**async def get_transaction(tx_hash):
    return(web3.eth.get_transaction(tx_hash)['hash'])**
```

it looks well, but after I ran this I found the speed is much slower than the first one, and after few minutes it will stuck, I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Are you using web3js or web3py, or both?

Comment: I'm using web3.py, the problem has already solved, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved the problem by using asyncio, by using the code below you can listen to all 721 and 1155 free mint events:

```
from urllib import response
from websockets import connect
from web3 import Web3
import json
import asyncio
import functools

alchemy_http_url = 'https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/<KEY>'
alchemy_ws_url = 'wss://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/<KEY>'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(alchemy_http_url))

erc721_log_filter = json.dumps({"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["logs", {'topics': [web3.sha3(text='Transfer(address,address,uint256)').hex()]}]})
erc1155_log_filter = json.dumps({"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id": 2, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["logs", {'topics': [web3.sha3(text='TransferSingle(address,address,address,uint256,uint256)').hex()]}]})

def get_transaction_721(transaction_hash):
    transacaction = (web3.eth.get_transaction(transaction_hash))
    value = transacaction['value']
    if value == 0:
        print('721===>',transacaction)

def get_transaction_1155(transaction_hash):
    transacaction = (web3.eth.get_transaction(transaction_hash))
    value = transacaction['value']
    if value == 0:
        print('1155===>',transacaction)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(erc1155_listener(),erc721_listener())

async def erc721_listener():
    running_loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    task_set = set()
    async with connect(alchemy_ws_url) as ws:
        await ws.send(erc721_log_filter)
        while True:
            try:
                message = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=60)
                event = json.loads(message)
                if len(event['params']['result']['topics']) == 4:
                    transaction_hash = event['params']['result']['transactionHash']
                    task = asyncio.create_task(running_loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(get_transaction_721, transaction_hash)))
                    task_set.add(task)
                    task.add_done_callback(task_set.discard)
                pass
            except:
                pass

async def erc1155_listener():
    running_loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    task_set = set()
    async with connect(alchemy_ws_url) as ws:
        await ws.send(erc1155_log_filter)
        while True:
            try:
                message = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=60)
                event = json.loads(message)
                transaction_hash = event['params']['result']['transactionHash']
                task = asyncio.create_task(running_loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(get_transaction_1155, transaction_hash)))
                task_set.add(task)
                task.add_done_callback(task_set.discard)
                pass
            except:
                pass

asyncio.run(main())
```